# Reference canvas prefab textfields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas prefab called ScoreMenu which I instantiate programmatically.

```
GameObject scoreMenu = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Menus/ScoreMenu"));
```

In my canvas I have several text fields and buttons. I'm having trouble referencing those text fields so I can change the contents of it.
My canvas has a script with a public `score` variable of type `Text`. Which I'm able to reference if it's of type `ScoreMenu`. But the instantiated object is of type `GameObject`. So I'm far unable to successfully cast it to another type so I can do things like `scoreMenu.score.text = "203";` 
I keep getting nullreference errors or casting error. What is the proper way to reference child objects of a canvas prefab?

UPDATE II:

I've narrowed down the problem.

```
    GameObject scores = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Menus/ScoreMenu")) as GameObject; 
    ScoreMenu scoresMenu = scores.GetComponent<ScoreMenu>();
```

This seems to be the correct way to instantiate and reference the prefab.
However the problem lies within the variables inside my prefab class.
Within my class I can reference and change the `Text`object. But when I try to do this outside the class I get a nullreference error.

```
public class ScoreMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text numStrokes;


    void OnAwake () {


    }

    void Start () {
        numStrokes = GameObject.Find("Strokes").GetComponent<Text>();
        numStrokes.text = "0000"; // this works
    }

    public void test () {

        print (numStrokes.text); // when calling this method from outside the class I get nullreference error

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I think.
I had to drag the texfield object from the hierarchy to the public variable field in the inspector.

[image]